# Can't make polygon/polyline/shape on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I made a polygon with external geojson file first and it works fine

```
var layer = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map)
```

then I made an array, tried to made a polygon/polyline from it, and zoom to polygon

the zoom parts works, I can pull any data from the array

```
var geo = selectCalc[0].geometry// my filtered array

var bounds = L.polygon(geo).getBounds(); // getBounds() works
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast(), //
    sw = bounds.getSouthWest()  //
                                //
var corner1 = [ne.lng, ne.lat], //
    corner2 = [sw.lng, sw.lat]  //--> this part just for invert the long lat

map.fitBounds([corner1, corner2])
```

I tried some method like `getCenter()` also works just fine, but when I try to add the shape from `geo` array, it didn't work. I also remove the geoJSON layer I made before to make sure is not sitting behind it.

**This part not working**

```
var focus = new L.polyline(geo)

    layerGroup.addLayer(focus) // premade layer group
```

**I did other method such as**

```
var focus = new L.polyline(geo).addTo(map)
```

any method such as `L.geoJson`, `L.polyline`, and `L.polygon` are not working. Is it the array type? but the `getBounds()` and `getCircle()` from the same array works just fine

Comment: Is not your `geo` data still with [lng, lat] order, whereas Leaflet expects [lat, lng] order? (Except for GeoJSON data, which order is specified to be [lng, lat])

Comment: @ghybs ah yes I think it is in different order. Took me a while to invert it, but I get it now. thanks!